# Java .class file info is already on RAM when it is generated. So why should jvm have a special method area?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm, stack

When we write code on a notepad or any IDE, all info is converted to bits on RAM. And the **.class** file after compilation already has instructions that jvm can understand. This info is also already on RAM when a .class file is created.

So why would jvm need special memory space on RAM called method area for **"loading class data".**
I learned that method area has metadata related to a class we execute.
But why would u need more memory space when u already have .class file info present on RAM when we run it.

Is it just for faster computing? Or the info on method area is totally different from what I understand.?

Comment: All data is bits in RAM (unless it's only on disk)

Comment: Hi @TimmyJoe, I'm having trouble understanding your question. Do you think of Java as an interpreted language, getting compiled everytime before execution? Otherwise it would make little sense. Sure, IDEs usually compile before execution, but that is not the case for a program that is built and then executed at a later time (as is the usual case). Could you clarify?

Comment: @TimmyJoe I guess the root of the confusion on my side is that if I compile a code on my machine (producing class files) and send the compiled program to your machine, the JVM will have to load the class files on your machine to execute them. Thus the question of why it doesn't use the in-memory version it got from compiling doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @TimmyJoe The JVM needs to load the class on runtime. Loading is done by ClassLoaders. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders

Answer (score 1):

> When we write code on a notepad or any IDE, all info is converted to bits on RAM.

All data on a computer is bits in RAM at some stage.

> And the .class file after compilation already has instructions that jvm can understand. This info is also already on RAM when a .class file is created.

It's not in RAM until the class file is created. The data in the class file is what is in RAM when the code is compiled.

> So why would jvm need special memory space on RAM called method area for "loading class data".

It has to be somewhere, and since it has a different lifecycle to other types of data it makes sense to manage it differently.

> I learned that method area has metadata related to a class we execute. But why would u need more memory space when u already have .class file info present on RAM when we run it.

You might need to unpack the information or turn it into native code for optimisation.

> Is it just for faster computing?

Yes, re-reading the .class file every time which be very slow.

> Or the info on method area is totally different from what I understand.?

It stores the information derived from the `.class` files as well as how the methods in the class are used.

Comment: @TimmyJoe the `.class` file is designed to be read once and the information you need to extract from it means taking a copy in the structure you need. If you want the code to be JITed, the x64 code created needs to be store somewhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused by the fact that modern operating systems have a virtual memory system. When you compile Java code the generated bytecodes will be held in physical memory as the compilation takes place.  However, the compiler has its own virtual address space. The virtual memory system maps physical addresses to process-specific virtual addresses. It also ensures that other processes cannot read or modify physical memory used by other processes (unless you use a special arrangement called shared memory).

When the JVM is running it has its own virtual memory address space and loads all the class file information into that address space.  To keep things organised it puts this data in the method area.

Theoretically, you could just read the compiled code directly from the area of memory used by the compiler process but it would be so complicated to make that work (and an unusual situation) that it is not done this way.